# Call to custom function is very slow

Tags: powershell

I have a newbie question on powershell (v4).

Given the following code,

- when I do $t = $i in the loop it takes 0.5s
- when I do $t = DoNothing($i) in the loop it takes 11.5s
- when I do $t = DoNothing $i in the loop it takes 11.5s

If I change content of function DoNothing to do something, the time doesn't extend much.

Obviously I have mad a big mistake somewhere but I can't see where it is. Thanks a lot for helping me understanding my mistake.

```
    function DoNothing($val) 
{
    return $val
}

Write-Host "Script started..."
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 


for($i=1
     $i -le 100000
     $i++){
     #$t = $i
     #$t = DoNothing($i)
     $t = DoNothing $i
     }

Write-Host "Script complete."
Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
```

Comment: I can confirm the behavior you are seeing. I get 0.2 seconds and 7 seconds respectively. I'll look into it, but it could just be the function overhead in PowerShell.

Comment: `DoNothing($i)` is not the correct PowerShell syntax (`DoNothing $i` is the correct syntax). But taking the actual question (which I presumed, as it is not specifically asked): (11.5s - 0.5s) * 60 * 1000 / 100000 = 6.6ms for interpreting a function, copying an argument in and return one. I think you expectation is simply to high...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I believe this is just the performance overhead of making function calls in PowerShell, but I did some experimentation to check.

A few things I noticed:

**1)** Saving the file increased performance around 75% compared to just working out of the PowerShell ISE without saving the file (From 7.3 seconds to 4.3 seconds).

**2)** Turning `DoNothing` into a parameterless function improved the execution time by an additional ~25% (From 4.3 seconds to 3.3 seconds). This would be useful if creating `$i` as a global variable would save time, but I tested that as well and, sadly, it increased execution time to 4.7 seconds.

**3)** I thought maybe explicitly requesting `$val` to be passed in as an int would decrease execution time, but it didn't. Time increased by about 0.2 seconds.

**4)** Naming the `-val` parameter when calling `DoNothing` (`$t = DoNothing -val $i`) did not improve performance.

**5)** Using `$val` instead of `return $val` did not improve performance.

**6)** Using `-lt` instead of `-le` did not improve performance.

**7)** Adding `DoNothing` to a PS module with only the `DoNothing` function in it severely decreased performance (from 4.3 seconds to 15 seconds).

So, I think this is all due to function overhead. I don't see anything 'wrong' in your code.

This has been an interesting experiment and might change when I choose to use PowerShell functions in the future. I wonder how this compares to other scripting languages.

Out of curiosity, I ran these same operations using C# and the whole thing completed in one one-thousandth of a second. Code is below.

```
class Program
{
    private static int DoNothing(int val) {
        return val;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            int t = DoNothing(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now I've gone a bit further than this. I figure if you really needed this to be faster, maybe you could throw the workload out to C# from PowerShell. This ended up being MUCH MUCH FASTER than the initial implementation in PowerShell, but slower than the C# only option. **This code runs in ~ 0.03 seconds.** See the code below.

**PowerShell** (calling the C#)

```
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Write-Host "Script started..."
$lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\you\source\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll")
$type = $lib.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1")
$method = $type.GetMethod("MyFunction")
$o = [Activator]::CreateInstance($type)
$method.Invoke($o, $null)
Write-Host "Script complete."
Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
```

**C#** (doing the work)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int DoNothing(int val)
        {
            return val;
        }

        public static void MyFunction()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
            {
                int t = DoNothing(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your work. Yes we will mix C# with PS, your answer will help us greatly.

Answer (score 0):

For information, in Python, the same thing (using function DoNothing) takes 0.01s. I don't know the main differences between Python and Powershell function handling but 0.01s vs 11.5s is 1k times faster...

```
import datetime

def DoNothing(val):
    return val

print("Script started...")
elapsed = datetime.datetime.now()


for i in range (1,100000):
    #t = i
    t = DoNothing(i)

print("Script complete.")
print('Total Elapsed Time: '+str(datetime.datetime.now() - elapsed))
```